# MySQL LEFT JOIN using OR is very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, join, mariadb, left-join

table users has about 80,000 records

table friends has about 900,000 records

There are 104 records with firstname = 'verena'

this query (the point of the query is gone because its very simplified) is very slow (> 20 seconds):

```
SELECT users.id FROM users
LEFT JOIN friends ON (
    users.id = friends.user_id OR
    users.id = friends.friend_id
)
WHERE users.firstname = 'verena';
```

However, if I remove the OR inside the JOIN, the query is instant, so either:

```
SELECT users.id FROM users
LEFT JOIN friends ON (
    users.id = friends.user_id
)
WHERE users.firstname = 'verena';
```

returning 1487 results or

```
SELECT users.id FROM users
LEFT JOIN friends ON (
    users.id = friends.friend_id
)
WHERE users.firstname = 'verena';
```

returning 2849 results
execute instantly (0.001s)

If I remove everything else and go straight for

```
SELECT 1 FROM friends WHERE user_id = xxx OR friend_id = xxx
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE firstname = 'verena';
```

these queries are also instant.

Indexes for friends.friend_id, friends.user_id and users.firstname are set.

I don't understand why the top query is slow while if manually taking it apart and executing the statements isolated everything is blazing fast.

My only suspicion now is that MariaDB is first joining ALL users with friends and only after that filters for WHERE firstname = 'verena', instead of the wanted behavior of first filtering for firstname = 'verena' and then joining the results with the friends table, but even then I don't see why removing the OR inside the JOIN condition would make it fast.

I tested this on 2 different machines, one running MariaDB 10.3.22 with Galera cluster and one with MariaDB 10.4.12 without Galera cluster

What is the technical reason why the top query is having such a huge slowdown and how do I fix this without having to split the SQL into several statements?

Edit:
Here is the EXPLAIN output for it, telling it's not using any index for the friends table and scanning through all records as correctly stated in Barmar's comment:

```
+------+-------------+---------+------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys     | key       | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                                          |
+------+-------------+---------+------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | users   | ref  | firstname         | firstname | 768     | const | 104    | Using where; Using index                       |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | friends | ALL  | user_id,friend_id | NULL      | NULL    | NULL  | 902853 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x6) |
+------+-------------+---------+------+-------------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there any way to make SQL use both indexes or do I just have to accept this limitation and work around it using for example Barmar's suggestion?

Comment: `OR` is generally slow on MySQL, because it can't be indexed. It's usually better to do two separate queries and merge them with `UNION`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Why can't SQL handle indexes if an OR is being used? What's the reason it wouldn't just use the index on friends.user_id first, and the index on friends.friend_id second?

Comment: It can only match one index per table in a join. So if it uses the index for `user_id`, it has to do a full scan for `friend_id`, and vice versa. So it just does a full scan for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is not usually able to use an index when you use `OR` to join with different columns. It can only use one index per table in a join, so if it uses the `friends.user_id` index, it won't use `friends.friend_id`, and vice versa.

The solution is to do the two fast queries and combine them with `UNION`.

```
SELECT users.id FROM users
LEFT JOIN friends ON (
    users.id = friends.user_id
)
WHERE users.firstname = 'verena';
UNION
SELECT users.id FROM users
LEFT JOIN friends ON (
    users.id = friends.friend_id
)
WHERE users.firstname = 'verena';
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but I'm really more interested in the "why" rather than a workaround

Comment: The real SQL is very long though, so having it double for the UNION SELECT would not be very pleasing, is there a better way without having to double up on code size?

Comment: Maybe you can do this union in a subquery and do all the common stuff in the main query. But other than that I don't have a recommendation, it's a MySQL design limitation.